# Python 2.7, Selenium, and PhantomJS Error

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, phantomjs

I installed Selenium v2.7 and PhantomJS v2.1. PhantomJS runs in my command prompt, but does not work in my program.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

driver.add_cookie({'PHPSESSID': '<mysessionid>'})
driver.get("http://csgodouble.com/")

print(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="past"]').text)
print driver.current_url
```

When I run the program, it outputs the error:

> driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PhantomJS'

How do I fix this? Thank you,

Comment: Can you run `pip list |grep selenium`? Also, is `phantomjs` on your PATH?

Comment: @AndrewRegan I'm on windows 8.1 and don't have grep. PhantomJS is on my PATH

Comment: OK, the selenium version you get from `pip list` (I should say that this is working for me)

Comment: I have Selenium (2.7.0) and Python 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two lines of your code are basically fine, but PhantomJS support wasn't added to Selenium Python [until version 2.27.0](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/selenium-2.27.0/py/selenium/webdriver) as far as I can tell, in December 2012.

So if `pip` is saying you have version 2.7.0 of the `selenium` module (from September 2011), all you should need to do is upgrade to the latest (2.52.0).

`pip uninstall selenium`

then: `pip install -U selenium` ([Install instructions](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium))